# Spring Batch, JpaRepository and Rollback

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application(Spring Boot 2.3.5.RELEASE) that uses a JpaRepository to insert some custom log messages into a database as Spring Batch is processing.  This is separate from the out of the box Spring Batch tables.  Seems that when I throw an exception from my ItemProcessorAdapter, it is caught by the ItemProcessListener onProcessError() method.  In this method I am performing a JpaRepository save() and flush().  No errors are logged, but once I leave this method the JpaRepository does a rollback.

1. Is this normal behavior?  How can I get around it?
2. When using JpaRepository, is there a way to set a @Transactional(noRollbackFor = {xxxException.class})?  I tried this and it seemed to have no effect.

Sample code snippet is below.

```java
@Configuration
public class BatchJobConfiguration {

   //Omitted for clarity....

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public CompositeItemProcessor<Decision,Decision> itemProcessor() {
        CompositeItemProcessor<Decision,Decision> itemProcessor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
        itemProcessor.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(
                decisionValidatingItemProcessor(),
                myItemProcessor(null)
        ));
        return itemProcessor;
    } // end itemProcessor()
    
     @Bean
    public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<Decision> decisionValidatingItemProcessor() {
        BeanValidatingItemProcessor<Decision> beanValidatingItemProcessor = new BeanValidatingItemProcessor<>();
        beanValidatingItemProcessor.setFilter(true);
        return beanValidatingItemProcessor;
    } // end decisionValidatingItemProcessor()

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessorAdapter<Decision,Decision> myItemProcessor(DecisionProcessingService service) {
        ItemProcessorAdapter<Decision,Decision> adapter = new ItemProcessorAdapter<>();
        adapter.setTargetObject(service);
        adapter.setTargetMethod("processDecision");
        return adapter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public DecisionItemProcessListener decisionItemProcessListener() {
        return new DecisionItemProcessListener(mpJpaRepository);
    }


}

@Service
public class DecisionProcessingService {

    public Decision processDecision(Decision decision) throws BatchException {
        ....
        throw new BatchException("An error occurred");
    
    }

}



public class DecisionItemProcessListener implements ItemProcessListener<Decision,Decision> {
    private MyJpaRepository mpJpaRepository;

    public DecisionItemProcessListener(MyJpaRepository mpJpaRepository) {
        this.mpJpaRepository = mpJpaRepository;
    }
    
    ....
    
    @Override
    public void onProcessError(Decision decision, Exception e) {
        MyEntityObject obj = MyEntityObject.builder()
                .msg(e.getMessage())
                .build();
        mpJpaRepository.save(obj);
        mpJpaRepository.flush();
        
        // after this, the insert above is rolled back.
    } // end onProcessError()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to log a error record in DB within ItemProcessListener - onProcessError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131204/unable-to-log-a-error-record-in-db-within-itemprocesslistener-onprocesserror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback you are using here `ItemProcessListener#onProcessError` is called with-in a transaction (driven by Spring Batch) that is going to be rolled-back due to the exception thrown by the item processor.

If you want to save data in that method, you need to use a new transaction (use the `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation).

**EDIT:**  I shared a minimal complete example here: https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/master/issues/so64913980.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I finally got around to trying this after a holiday here.  Your suggestion didn't seem to make any difference. I added the following to the ItemProcessor service I created.

    `@Service
    @StepScope
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "batchTransactionManager", propagation =  Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public class DecisionProcessingService {`

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed your issue. This is what I meant by using a new transaction with the `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation. This separate transaction will not be rolled back when the main one (driven by spring batch) is rolled back.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud.  Just to clarify.  This did not fix the issue.  It's still rolling back.

Comment: I shared a complete example here: https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/master/issues/so64913980. You will see that with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the `ItemProcessListener#onProcessError`, processing errors are persisted as expected thanks to the separate transaction. If you remove that, they are not persisted anymore since the method is called in the same transaction that is being rolled back. Hope this help.

Comment: I'll go through your sample and compare to mine to see if I missed something.  I won't get to this until tomorrow(Wednesday Dec. 2), so I will reply either way at that time.  Thank you.

Comment: Mahmoud.  Thank you for your patience, and for the sample code.  Using it, I was able to identify my error.  I was using a separate class that implemented `ItemProcessListener`.  When doing that, no matter where I put the `@Transactional` annotation it basically did nothing.  

Thanks again.  All is good now.

Comment: Great to hear you fixed your issue. I'm glad the answer/sample helped!